# Correct grammar forms

Tags: grammar

1. Is only one form possible in the sentence:

> The name Alaska comes from the Aleut word alaxsxaq, __________ (mean) "object toward which the action of the sea is directed" - that is the mainland.

Can we only use here the Word "meaning" or the Word "means" also possible?

2. In the sentence:

> It is also known as Alyeska, "the great land", an Aleut Word __________ (form) from the same root.

Can we use here two variants 1) formed and 2) is formed?

Comment: 'A word meaning XXXX' or 'A word _which_ means XXXXX'. Similarly, 'A word formed from  YYYYY' or (possibly) 'A word _which was_ formed from YYYYY'.

Comment: The present simple verb form "*means*" requires a subject. Where's the subject of that verb?

Comment: If we think that the subject for means is Alaska? Alaska means...

Comment: @Fatimahon Yes, "Alaska means ___" is grammatically correct and clear.  But that is not what this sentence says.  *Alaska* is the subject, and *comes from* is the main verb.  *mean* is not the main verb here, so you don't conjugate it that way.